# OptaPlanner ECJ dependency. Replace or pre-compile drools for on-prem installation

Tags: drools, optaplanner

We have been using OptaPlanner for a potential On-Prem/Cloud solution. We are currently using drools-rules that are compiled at runtime (i think the default behaviour?).

OptaPlanner is pulling in the "Eclipse ECJ" dependency via the Drools compiler.

`optaplanner-core -> drools-compiler -> ecj`

ECJ uses the EPL 1.0 licence which we have been instructed should not be distributed.

My question(s):

- Does OptaPlanner support pre-compiled drools rules?
- Are there any alternatives if we were to exclude 'ecj'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConstraintStreams are probably a way to avoid ECJ, as the Drools implementation won't compile DRL. And the faster Bavet implementation won't use Drools at all. However, ConstraintStreams are still young... (but very actively being worked on).

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey, We will take a look and see if it covers everything we need.

Comment: I will depend. ConstraintsStreams are young. If they don't support enough today or aren't fast enough today, don't judge them by those results in a year from now.

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey, We have now switched over to using Constraint Streams and it covers everything we need at the moment, and is a little quicker as well. We don't have an overly complex set of rules, but a quick and dirty test gives us:- 

drools file around 33 seconds, constraintstreams API around 22 seconds

Comment: Bavet or Drools? note that if you don't specifically set constraintStreamImplType, the default recently changed. (Drools is more feature complete, bavet is faster)

Comment: Drools. We tried Bavet but it caused corruptions and we haven't looked further into why.

Comment: Corruptions or UnsupportedOperationException? If it's an actual score corruption, I want to know how to reproduce it, because we want to fix it ASAP. If it's an UnsupportedOperationException, it's some features we don't support yet on bavet.

Comment: We haven't been able to cut down our code to a reproducible example, so we are not sure if it is a problem with our code specifically or not, so take this with a grain of salt.

It seems to be an issue if we do a problem fact change just after the CH phase completes, the exception follows the form:
https://pastebin.com/70E9vX6c

Comment: That's a clear BAVET bug. I'd love to get a reproducer so I can fix it. My e-mail's is on the optaplanner team page.